Concept on potential energy in each state of matter
I'm revising the concept of internal energy and i'm finding myself very confused with the concept of potential energy.
Most places I look say that solids and liquids have a greater potential energy than gases, however, I don't understand how this is possible considering that there is an increase in potential energy when energy is added to change from one state to another (e.g. from liquid to gas).
I'm also not understanding the intuitive concept of potential energy in this context. With other forms of potential energy, such as GPE, I can see how a body can have potential energy at a height above the ground due to it's ability to transform the GPE to kinetic energy as it falls. However, I'm not really understanding the relation between potential energy and intermolecular forces in this context.
If anybody could clear up these concepts it would be great.

It's not clear whether your question is about internal energy or about potential energy. Example: a boat fender. When the boat bumps another boat then the air inside the fender is transiently compressed. Work is done on the air, and some of that work goes to temperature increase of that air. On the rebound that heat converts back to kinetic energy of the boat. That heat is counted as internal energy. Now: as we know: heat is kinetic energy of molecules. That is to say: 'internal energy' and 'potential energy' aren't necessarily the same thing.


Most places I look say that solids and liquids have
a greater potential energy than gases, however,
I don't understand how this is possible considering
that there is an increase in potential energy when energy is
added to change from one state to another (e.g. from liquid to gas).

Potential between atoms or molecules usually is negative.

For example, in a gas the potential energy between two molecules
is nearly zero when the molecules are far apart.
And in a liquid (where the molecules are close to each other)
the potential energy between them is large and negative.
Therefore, when a gas condensates to a liquid the potential
energy decreases and the difference is released
to the environment.

I'm also not understanding the intuitive concept of
potential energy in this context. With other forms
of potential energy, such as GPE, I can see how a body
can have potential energy at a height above the ground
due to it's ability to transform the GPE to kinetic energy as it falls.

The above described decrease of intermolecular potential energy
is similar to the decrease of gravititational potential
energy of a falling body.

In this context, I say it is best to think of potential energy in terms of the intermolecular forces between the atoms due to electrostatic attraction.
Now, as the magnitude of the Coulomb potential between charges $q_1,q_2$ is $U = \frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$, where $r$ is the distance between the charges. As the atoms are held together closer ($r$ decreases) and the prevalence of these intermolecular forces increase, such as in liquids and solids (as these states are partially defined by the prevalence of such forces), $U \propto \frac{1}{r}$ would increase.
Don't hesitate to ask any questions or correct me whenever necessary, but I find it useful to think about it this way.

Thanks for the awnser, I see how that explains why solids and liquids have a greater potential energy. However, what I still don't understand is why changing from for example, liquid to gas, causes an increase in potential energy yet gases have lower potential energy than liquids.

When you cause a solid to melt to a liquid or a liquid to evaporate to a gas by heating it (or, indeed, cause a solid to sublime to a gas), the heat energy does two things. Firstly, it increase the average kinetic energy of the atoms/molecules in the substance i.e. in macroscopic terms it raises its temperature. Secondly, it breaks the bonds that connect the atoms/molecules together in the solid or liquid form. In macroscopic terms, the energy required to break these bonds is the latent heat of transformation.
So a liquid (for example) has lower average potential energy stored in its inter-molecular bonds than the equivalent solid, but it has much higher average kinetic energy, and the increase in average kinetic energy is more than enough to account for the lower potential energy.
